# How to set up a multiple speakers to one notebook?

Tags: speakers, experimental, multiple

I am going to perform an experiment with **3 different sound tracks emitted simultaneously by 3 speakers** and I would like to know how the apparatus need to be set up to one notebook.

Any suggestions are welcomed. **Is it possible to make somehow such settings in Audacity** (***Ubuntu solution is preferred***)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this setup, you will need :

- an USB external audio interface that offers at least 3 analog outputs. Check that the chosen interface software driver is well supported on GNU/Linux/Ubuntu.
- a software player that allow playing several tracks at once. It also must be able to route individual tracks to dedicated interface outputs. I am not sure that Audacity will do for three outputs, but [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) will for sure.

You might have a look at [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/), a distribution that includes Ardour.

Comment: Hi @audionuma ! Thank you for answer. Could you please add some (shop) link to such USB device?

Comment: You can have a look here : http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/hardware_support to find a suitable model. Finding a store will then be easy.

Answer (score 1):

With some DJ software you can do it, but I think that this solution is not for Ubuntu: In Native Instruments Traktor, you can route each deck to a different output, but you need to have also a compatible soundcard (I mean, at least 3 outputs).

You will be good with mono output because you talk about one speaker per track, so if a soundcard offers 2 stereo outputs, you have then 4 mono outputs, so this can be done easily.

[image: Traktor routing settings]

If you cannot use NI Traktor, try using this concept in some similar software.

Cheers.